# mysql query that doesn't show fields that are empty

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have the query

```
SELECT id_address, address1, address2 
FROM ps_address 
WHERE address1 REGEXP '[[:digit:]]'
```

The query returns 2 columns with data but also empty fields

[image]

how can i make the query that it doesn't show does empty fields anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `address2 <> ""` to your `where` condition and it will remove result with empty `address2`.

```
SELECT id_address, address1, address2 
FROM ps_address 
WHERE address1 REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' AND address2 <> ''
```

Comment: what if address2 = '[SPACE]'. You should trim it

Comment: Considering that he said empty, I won't conclude that he wants to remove empty space as well (just in case). Otherwise, I use `TRIM(address2 ) <> ''`

Comment: That was what i meant.

Comment: The point here is if the guy have 20 billions row to check, and he knows there is no one white space, you will considerably slowdown the speed execution for absolutely no reason right

Answer (score 0):

you should check if its an empty string. Also dont forget to TRIM() your columns to prevent any whitespaces to appear.

```
SELECT id_address, address1, address2 
FROM ps_address 
WHERE address1 REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' and TRIM(address2) <> '' and TRIM(address1) <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the empty fields in the address2 column, the question I would want to answer is what is in the empty fields? Is it a space? Multiple spaces? An empty string? Once we answer that question a query as simple as the following could work.

```
SELECT id_address, address1, address2 
FROM ps_address 
WHERE address1 REGEXP '[[:digit:]]'
    AND address2 != ''
```

Or here is another option if you don't know what the empty fields are but you know they aren't NULL.

```
SELECT id_address, address1, address2 
FROM ps_address 
WHERE address1 REGEXP '[[:digit:]]'
    AND address2 NOT REGEXP '/s*'
```

Does that make sense? or am I not understanding your question?